# Show all rows with 0 if no records found on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-null

I need to see all the records from table A, if no matching record found on table B then show 0 with  corresponding value of A.

```
SELECT r.date
     , l.total_user
  FROM daterange r
  LEFT 
  JOIN logs l
    ON r.date = l.created_date
 WHERE r.date BETWEEN '2020-09-14' AND '2020-11-14' AND   l.view_id =(SELECT view_id from logs where user_id = 63)
```

in above query few records doesn't exist in logs table but i need 0 with date as well.

Any idea how to resolve this please

i need all dates from '2020-09-14' to  '2020-11-14' from daterange table

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want `coalesce()`:

```
select d.date, coalesce(l.total_user, 0) as total_user
from daterange d 
left join logs l on d.date = l.created_date
where d.date between '2020-09-14' and '2020-11-14'
```

When there is no match for a given `date` in the `logs` table, this returns `0` for `total_user` instead of `null`. Of course, this assumes that column `total_user` is of a numeric datatype to start with.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: this is missing '2020-09-14' and if i use one more condition like  

select d.date, coalesce(l.total_user, 0) as total_user
from daterange d 
left join logs l on d.date = l.created_date
where d.date between '2020-09-14' and '2020-11-14' AND l.`view_id` =(SELECT view_id  from logs where user_id = 63). its giving few records

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL() function.

```
SELECT r.date
     , IFNULL(l.total_user, 0)
  FROM daterange r
  LEFT 
  JOIN logs l
    ON r.date = l.created_date
 WHERE r.date BETWEEN '2020-09-14' AND '2020-11-14' AND   l.view_id =(SELECT 
 view_id from logs where user_id = 63)
```

Comment: this is missing '2020-09-14' and if i use one more condition like select d.date, coalesce(l.total_user, 0) as total_user from daterange d left join logs l on d.date = l.created_date where d.date between '2020-09-14' and '2020-11-14' AND l.view_id =(SELECT view_id from logs where user_id = 63). its giving few records –

Comment: this query is working fine but not giving me all results. this is only giving me matching records now

Comment: Can you edit the question to be more descriptive? You can add expected and actual results.